# Find the area of triangle BCD in the following figure

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Triangles on same base]

I have tried the following:

Since CD is median, area of Triangle BCD is half the area of triangle BCQ.Area of BCQ is 1/2*BQ*CD' where CD' is the altitude. Now we have to find CD'. This is where I am stuck.

How to find out the height of Traingle BCQ in this? Do we apply the concept of triangles on same base? Posted here only after trying my best.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far did you get? Where are you stuck? This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Since CD is median, area of Triangle BCD is half the area of triangle BCQ.

Comment: Then what’s the area of triangle ABQ? You know the answer has to be less than half of that.

Comment: Base is 50, height is less than 10, so area must be less than 250, so option (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments, the answer must be (a).

However, to prove this if the answers had not been given, drop a perpendicular, $CE$, of height $h$ from $C$ onto $BQ$ where $BE=x$.

By similar triangles, $\frac{10}{h}=\frac{100}{100-x}$ and $\frac{40}{h}=\frac{100}{x}$.

Then $x=20,h=8$ and so the required area is $\frac{1}{2}\times50\times h=200$.

N.B. A neat general result for this set up is that the reciprocal of $h$ is the sum of the reciprocals of the two given heights i.e.

$$\frac{1}{h}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{40}.$$

**Proof**

Let the given heights be $L,M$ and the base $D$. By similar triangles:
$$\frac{L}{h}=\frac{D}{D-x}\text { and }\frac{M}{h}=\frac{D}{x}.$$ Then $$\frac{D-x}{hD}=\frac{1}{L}\text { and }\frac{x}{hD}=\frac{1}{M}.$$ Now add the two LH terms: $$\frac{D-x}{hD}\text +\frac{x}{hD}=\frac{D}{hD}=\frac{1}{h}$$ and so $$\frac{1}{h}=\frac{1}{L}+\frac{1}{M}.$$

Comment: how is that general result established?

Comment: Exactly the same way! I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Let [.] denote areas. Then,

$$[ABC]+[CBQ]=[ABQ] = \frac12\cdot AB \cdot BQ = 500\tag 1$$

$$\frac{[ABC]}{[CBQ]}= \frac{AC}{CQ} = \frac{AB}{PQ} = \frac14\tag 2$$

Substitute (1) into (2) to obtain $[CBQ] = 400$. Thus, $[BDC] = \frac12 [CBQ] = \frac{400}2= 200$.

Comment: I didnt get how area of ABC by area of CBQ is AC by CQ??

Comment: @paidedly - ABC and CBQ share the base BC